# realtime network statistics on iOS

Tags: ios, usage-statistics

I know it is possible to check the traffic usage of wifi and Data through built-in settings in iphone. But is there any solution like a library or function to fetch realtime network usage (upload/download) of the device? (like a real time netstat)

Reachability is one of the things that I found with regard to the mentioned.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

this app does something similar:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/data-control-manage-data-usage/id390646992?mt=8

Does anyone know what class to call or look for what certain method to access the real time traffic?

I hope that my question is understandable.

Comment: Are you talking about tracking usage for your app or overall?

Answer (score 1):

There is no high level API to support this, but since iOS is simply a rather pretty unix, you can of course go to the standard APIs.

In this case you would be looking for getifaddrs, which retrieves the in memory structures describing the various interfaces on the device.

You then have to parse these C structures, to get the interface details you want.

The getifaddr interface *is* documented ( man getifaddr), so you can use this.

I'll add a bit of code, but first a few caveats.
Apple don't really bother maintaining this stuff, so the network counts are 32 bit, so you have to handle 4Gb roll over.
The packet counts are mostly there, I think the tx packet count is always 0, but who is interested in packet counts anyway.

You can probably find better code here by searching for getifaddrs, but here is a short version to get you started.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if_var.h>

    struct ifaddrs* addrs;

    int getIFAddrsResult = getifaddrs(&addrs);
    if (getIFAddrsResult == 0)
    {
        struct ifaddrs* addrsPtr = addrs; // need to keep original for freeifaddrs
        while (addrsPtr != NULL)
        {
            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",addrsPtr->ifa_name];
            //NSLog(@"ifa_name %s == %@\n", cursor->ifa_name,name);
            // names of interfaces: en0 is WiFi ,pdp_ip0 is WWAN

            if (addrsPtr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK)
            {
                const struct if_data* stats = (const struct if_data *) addrsPtr->ifa_data;

                // We only consider the active data interface, and that will normally be the '0' interface.
                if ([name isEqualToString:@"en0"])
                {
                     // Wifi
                     // look at stats->ifi_obytes & ifi_ibytes

                } else if ([name isEqualToString:@"pdp_ip0"])
                {
                   // mobile broad band
                } else {
                   // could be bluetooth, usb, ad hoc wifi, out of band signalling...
                }
            }

            addrsPtr = addrsPtr->ifa_next;
        }

        freeifaddrs(addrs);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"getifaddrs failed with error : %s", strerror(getIFAddrsResult));
        return nil;
    }
```

P.S. I'm going for my diamond resurrect old questions badge :)

Answer (score -1):

There is no such API in iOS, the App that you mentioned (and all similar apps), rely on an API provided by the carrier (or parsing the carriers website). If you want to implement this kind of App, I'm afraid you have to find something for every possible carrier you are interested in.